# HiveQL - String contains equivalent in hiveql UDF?

Tags: sql, string, hive, substring, hiveql

I would like to use hiveql UDF to check whether the string contains any specific character or not?

I came across the below one.

```
find_in_set(str, strlist)
```

Is this the correct UDF to use?

**For example:**

the below column contains "1" in the value.

```
column1 = "test1String"
```

i need to write a HiveQL where condition to return the rows with column1 value contains 1.

Comment: You already has an answer in last your last question's answer, @Gordon Linoff one. `where column1 rlike '[1]'`

Comment: @syadav : Thanks mate..

Answer (score 7):

```
int instr(string str, string substr)
```

Returns the position of the first occurrence of substr in str. Returns null if either of the arguments are null and returns 0 if substr could not be found in str. Be aware that this is not zero based. The first character in str has index 1.

```
select case when instr (column1, '1') >0 then 'contains' else 'not contains' end from ...
```

See this for reference: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Also using `rlike`:

```
select case when column1 rlike '1'  then 'contains' else 'not contains' end
```

Using `like`:

```
select case when column1 like '%1%'  then 'contains' else 'not contains' end
```

Using `locate`:

```
select case when locate('1', column1) >0 then 'contains' else 'not contains' end
```